# Overleaf XeLatex: Comic Sans Italic isn't found

Tags: fonts, latex, xelatex

I can't make Comic Sans Italic work in Overleaf, XeLatex.

```
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}[ItalicFont = {comici.ttf}]
\setsansfont{Comic Sans MS}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing
%--------------------------------------
```

When I put

```
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}[ItalicFont = Comic Sans MS Italic]
```

it can't be found (though font is installed on my system), when I upload ttf to it, I can format the whole document in it with

```
\setmainfont{[comici.ttf]}
```

but I want to connect it only with italic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload Comic-Sans-Regilar.ttf and Comic-Sans-Italic.ttf and also bold one to your root and use this code:

```
\setmainfont{Comic-Sans}[ 
Extension = .ttf,
UprightFont = *-Regular,
ItalicFont = *-Italic,
BoldFont = *-Bold]
```